# Mejor librería para programación de aplicaciones TUI (interfaz de usuario en modo texto)

Tags: consola

¿Alguien sabe cuál es, hoy por hoy, la mejor librería para programar aplicaciones en modo texto (consola)?

Estoy mirando `ncurses` pero supongo que habrá alguna más actual. Lo que sí me gustaría es que pudiera hacer aplicaciones que funcionaran incluso por ssh.

Comment: Pese a indicarte una respuesta, me veo en la obligación de votar para cerrarla, por estar, precisamente, basada en opiniones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mejor ... pues es cuestión de gustos.

No descartes la `ncurses`, es perfectamente válida. Algo antigua, eso sí.

Puedes probar también la `libcwidget` para C++, en la que se basa la aplicación `aptitude`, o la `slang`, esta para C, y en la cual se base `mc` ( Midnight Commander ).

Lo del ssh, me temo que te confundes. Depende del **cliente** que uses, no del protocolo en sí. Mas concretamente, de la emulación de terminal que implemente: vt100, vt101, ANSI, ... cada una proporciona una u otras ventajas e inconvenientes; por ejemplo, el vt100 es en B/N, no soporta color.

Comment: Muy buena contestación @Trauma. Me gustaría usar más de 16 colores, qué emulación de terminal debería usar?

Comment: Una con bastante soporte (PuTTY incluido) es la `xterm`, que permite hasta 256 colores. Suele estar incluida en casi todas las definiciones de terminal. En Ubuntu, se instala obligatoria, con el paquete `ncurses-base`.

Comment: He estado mirando `libtcod`, sabes si si permite hacer aplicaciones de consola? lo digo porque según parece usa la librería gráfica SDL. Me tiene despistado.

Comment: No he usado SDL desde hace muuuuchooo. libtcod usa SDL 2, y la doc de esta última no indica todos los *drivers* que soporta. En la FAQ indica que aún soporta libaa, que es para consola, pero en B/N. Para color, SDL 1.2 usaba libcaca, pero en SDL 2 no lo indica por ningún lado. Tal vez en las fuentes. NO confundas *framebuffer* con *terminal*, que no es lo mismo.

Comment: como siempre gracias por tu respuesta. Qué diferencia hay entre framebuffer con terminal? Framebuffer puedo usarlo a través de ssh en un emulador xterm?

Comment: Nope. `framebuffer` es, a grandes rasgos, un método de acceso **local** a la memoria de la tarjeta gráfica; **no** niego que exista alguna librería que permita hacer eso en remoto, pero entonces no sería usable **directamente** desde ssh. *terminal* indica eso, que se emula un terminal de texto tradicional, *controlable* hasta cierto punto mediante secuencias concretas de *bytes*, y que trabaja con caracteres y no gráficos. Pueden existir terminales que soporten gráficos (lo ignoro). Para estas preguntas *informales*, te sugiero que uses el **chat**, cuando tengas 20 puntos o mas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52235/discussion-between-amparo-and-trauma).